# cassandra-stress tool: [a-z] letters range for varchar column

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-stress

Under `cassandra-stress` yaml config file, `columnspec` defines insert range of data.

For a `varchar` column how to say I want a column to be populated with words built from letters `[a-z]*` only?

If I say:

```
columnspec:
  - name: id # varchar
  - population: uniform(100..110)
```

I get stings like this: `\x1c\x0b\x1bK]`

Comment: How to query by `\x1c\x0b\x1bK]`? This is not working with cqlsh: `select * from table where id = '\x1c\x0b\x1bK]'`

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem?